# Getting Data Provider Mismatch error while trying to fetch data from excel

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to learn DataProvider test annotation wherein I am reading the test data from an excel file and then send that as the input for the test case. But I'm getting below error on executing the same:

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
>   FAILED: loginTest
>   org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
>   Data provider mismatch

Here is the code below:

## ExcelUtilites.java

```
public class ExcelUtilites {

    public static ArrayList<Object> getDataFromExcel() throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException
    {
        ArrayList<Object> al=new ArrayList<Object>();
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("E:\\LoginData.xlsx");
        Workbook wb=WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        Sheet sh=wb.getSheet("Logins");
        Row rows=sh.getRow(0);
        Cell cells=rows.getCell(0);

        for(int rowCount=0;rowCount<sh.getLastRowNum();rowCount++)
        {
            String username=sh.getRow(rowCount).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            String password=sh.getRow(rowCount).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

            Object[] ob={username,password};
            al.add(ob);

        }
        return al;

    }

}
```

## FacebookTest.java

```
public class FacebookTest {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
                "E:\\All_JARs\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "fetchDatafromExcel")
    public void loginTest(String username, String password) {

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys(
                username);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys(
                password);
        driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("//input[@data-testid='royal_login_button']")).click();

    }

    @DataProvider(name = "fetchDatafromExcel")
    public Iterator<Object> fetchDatafromExcel()
            throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException,
            IOException {
        ArrayList<Object> testdata = ExcelUtilites.getDataFromExcel();
        return testdata.iterator();

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Comment: How many column are there in your excel sheet which having data ?

Comment: There are 2 columns-Username and Password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type from the dataprovider is `Iterator<Object[]>`. You are missing the array part. The test method needs to have the `Object` as the parameter.

Added some generic code, implement the excel access logic within this.

```
public class Credentials {

    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public Credentials() {  }

    public Credentials(String userName, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUserName() { return userName;  }

    public void setUserName(String userName) { this.userName = userName; }

    public String getPassword() { return password;  }

    public void setPassword(String password) {  this.password = password; }
}
```

---

```
    @Test(dataProvider = "dpit")
    public void f(Credentials cred) {
        System.out.println(cred.getUserName());
        System.out.println(cred.getPassword());
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "dpit")
    public Iterator<Credentials[]> createData() {

        Credentials[] s1arr = {new Credentials("hello", "hellopass")};
        Credentials[] s2arr = {new Credentials("bye", "byepass")};

        List<Credentials[]> sm = new ArrayList<>();
        sm.add(s1arr);
        sm.add(s2arr);

        return sm.iterator();
    }
```